# Can I detect different clients from same IP in TcpConnections?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

Can we detect different clients(devices) from same IP on TCPConnection ?

Example :

I have a TCP Server called s1 and I have 2 PCs called p1,p2 and my PCs IP is same (e.g. 1.2.3.4)
when I connect to s1 (my TCP Server) with p1 and p2 (Pc1 and Pc2) can s1(my TCP server) detect these clients with same IP, isn't same device ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are basically asking to detect different devices behind a NAT, i.e. devices sharing the same external IP address. There is no fully reliable way to do this but one can employ heuristics. Typically these are based on the ID field in the IP header and/or the TCP timestamp option, see for example [A Technique for Counting NATted Hosts](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Esmb/papers/fnat.pdf) or [Time has something to tell us about Network
Address Translation](http://www.lsv.fr/Publis/PAPERS/PDF/Bur-nordsec07.pdf). One might also try to use passive OS fingerprinting in order to detect if different OS are used (and thus different real or virtual devices) - see [Passive Fingerprinting](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/passive-fingerprinting).

None of these heuristics are fully reliable though and they also will not work if the devices are behind a proxy, since in this case the TCP/IP connections visible to the server originate from a single device - the proxy.

Comment: You are AWESOME Men :))) Can you say how to use passive OS fingerprinting in any language ?

Comment: @mahdimds:  See for example https://pypi.org/project/p0f/ for using one of the major OS fingerprinting libraries from Python.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. The server can ask the operating system for the connection information of client associated with the socket. In 'C' this would look [like](https://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/#:%7E:text=Get%20the%20ip%20address%20of,int%20client_port%20%3D%20ntohs(client)):

```
//Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (new_socket<0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

The `client` sockaddr structure will be filled with the information about the connecting client. The server can look into this to extract the IP Address as a string doing something like:

```
char *ip = inet_ntoa((struct sockaddr_in *)client.sin_addr);
```

You can now see if `ip` matches p1 or p2.

Comment: No, you don't understood my question. I have a server . and I have 2 PC with same ip(PC1 = 1.2.3.4 and PC2=1.2.3.4 too) My question is if this 2 PCs connect to server, Can server detect this 2PCs are Different ?

Comment: Or server can ask the client what is your OS ?

Comment: I see you are assuming a NAT case.